# Syntax for using other fields in Advanced Python field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, syntax, advanced-python-field-calculator

What is the syntax for the "Advanced Python field calculator" when using other fields as input in QGIS 3.2.20?

(The example below is not the actual function. I have a complex if-else, assigning variables etc. which will be complicated to replicate using `CASE WHEN`'s in the standard Field calculator).

For example, if I have a field called `"SOURCE"` and want to calculate a new field with source as input?

This approach

```
value = SOURCE.lower()
```

gives me the following error:

> FieldPyculator code execute error. Field code block can't be executed!
> SyntaxError

I tried: `"SOURCE", 'SOURCE', <SOURCE>, !SOURCE!, [SOURCE]`, unfortunately none of them works.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advanced Python calculator usually expects that you enter an expression in the Global expression (otherwise you could rather consider the standard field calculator). In my humble opinion this clarifies the use of the variables. The simplest form is to enter a function

```
def myfunction(myparam):
 output = doSomething(myparam)
 return output
```

then you can use this funtion to return the value

```
value = myfunction(<myfield>)
```

in your case, the content of the function will be

```
output = myparam.lower()
return output
```

or in one line...

```
return myparam.lower()
```

Answer (score 5):

I could refer to your `"SOURCE"` field using the `<SOURCE>` notation:

```py
value = <SOURCE>.lower()
```

and I did not get any error back, see image below.

[image: result]

Alternatively you can refer to your field by its index (starts with `0`):

```py
value = __attr[1].lower()
```

In both cases the usage of [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function maybe required, i.e. `value =  str(<SOURCE>).lower()`

Because as set in [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#advanced-python-field-calculator) your formula Formula accepts either `str` or [`QgsProperty`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Property/QgsProperty.html) data type.

As was mentioned in [Issue #18394 on GitHub: Advanced Python field calculator needs documentation](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/18394):

> Since the syntax is not standard QGIS field calculator syntax, users
> definitely need documentation here.
>
> I've written down some
> "notes":http://anitagraser.com/2013/04/20/advanced-python-field-calculator/
> ... especially that you have to put attribute names in pointy brackets
> is tricky.

Also, good to check this article [Date-format conversion](https://newbedev.com/date-format-conversion) in which it highlights that

> It opens up the following window. Note that the input layer and
> options for a new field have been filled out. In addition, the code
> has been placed in the lower window, which will be applied to each row
> in the dataset. You reference a field by placing the name inside
> carets, like so: `<field name>`

This source [Syntax bedingter Anweisungen in QGIS-Feldrechnern](https://qastack.com.de/gis/84813/syntax-of-conditional-statements-in-qgis-field-calculators) says that (translated from German):

> The syntax of the Advanced Python field calculator in the Processing
> Toolbox differs from one of the standard QGIS Field calculator.
>
> It is possible to use the Advanced Python field calculator in Modeler.
> However, you must specify the source fields directly in the formula
> because fields cannot be used as input parameters when using this
> algorithm. Alternatively, you can define an input string parameter
> that contains the standard formula. When you run the model, you may be
> able to change the source fields in the Formula input parameter so
> that the model is perfectly reusable for other data.

---

**References:**

- [GitHub | QGIS | FieldPyculator.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/91c536466690eb04466d4a4e1ae03c3e2180fa13/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/FieldPyculator.py#L125)
- [Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings | Advanced Python Field Calculator](https://anitagraser.com/2013/04/20/advanced-python-field-calculator/)