# Use algorithm output as expression in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, clustering, qgis-expression, advanced-python-field-calculator

I want to use the algorithm output within the input expression of another algorithm in the Graphical Modeler of QGIS 3.30.3.
Specifically, I want to create clusters of areas previously identified as suitable `Suitable Areas` with the algorithm `K-means clustering`. The number of clusters is defined as the quotient of the complete area of the suitable areas and the minimum cluster size `Minimal Cluster Size [km²]`.
The graphical model looks as follows:

[image: Graphical model]

`Minimal Cluster Size [km²]` is a numeric input parameter.
`Suitable Areas` is a polygon input, which is dissolved to one single feature using `Dissolve`, which allows the calculation of the complete area of the suitable areas.
In the `Advanced Python field calculator` I choose Pre-calculated Value for the formula:

[image: Advanced Python field calculator]

I receive the number of clusters, I calculate the area with `$area`, convert it from square meters to sqaure kilometers by `/ 10^6` and divide it by the `Minimal Cluster Size [km²]` with `/ @minimal_cluster_size_km`.
I tried several versions of the formula, but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly.
The Log file displays: Error encountered while running Advanced Python field calculator
In the next step I want to cluster the `Suitable Areas` with the algorithm `K-means clustering`.

[image: K-means clustering]

Here I want to use the output of the `Advanced Python field calculator` as the number of clusters.
I am also not sure if the expression is correctly applied here.

---

Edit:

As suggested in the comment the change from the `Advanced Python field calculator` to the `Field calculator` works and the generated output contains a column with the number of clusters. Here I also changed the `Field type` to integer to receive a whole number.

[image]

The problem I have now is accessing the calculated number of clusters within the `K-means clustering`. The expression `@Field_calculator_OUTPUT` is not working, as it uses the complete output as an input. I tried deleting the other columns of the attribute table with `Refactor fields` and take this as the input of the `K-means clustering`. But this does also not workand produces the same output as before. Is there a simple way of accessing this one specific feature with the calculated number of clusters or do I have to use another algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! For what reason do you use the `Advanced Python field calculator` instead of just the `Field calculator`? If you really want to use the Python version, [the syntax is different](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/416491/52808) (Python code, actually!). But using your expression inside the normal field calculator should work (without having checked if the result is exactly what you need).

Comment: Thanks, there is no specific reason why I chose the `Advanced Python field calculator` over the `Field calculator`. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: if you were able to answer your question with this, I suggest you write this answer yourself and accept it as solving your problem. In this way others can easily spot that you found what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will write an answer.
However, I am still struggling with accessing the calculated number of clusters within the K-means clustering algorithm, which delivers 5 clusters, altough the calculated number of clusters is way higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my initial problem.
First I changed the `Advanced Python field calculator` to the `Field calculator` using the same expression. Than I used `Refactor fields` to get rid of the other columns in my attribute table. Afterwards I used `Basic statistics for fields` that generates an output that can be utilized as an input for the `K-means clustering algorithm`.

[image]

[image]

There might be a more straightforward solution to the problem.